# how can I add css class to a django form field that is generated by RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper

Tags: django

how can I apply css classes to the guardian field. In the following code I used widgets option in the Meta class but that does not change any style.
this is forms.py

```
class StudentProfileForm(ProfileForm):
    guardian = Student._meta.get_field('guardian').formfield(
        widget=RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
            Student._meta.get_field('guardian').formfield().widget,
            Student._meta.get_field('guardian').remote_field,
            accounts_admin_site,
            can_add_related=True,
        )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        widgets = {'guardian' : forms.Select(attrs={'class':'selectpicker'})}
        exclude = ['user', 'guardian', 'salary', 'date_left', 'contact_number', 'status', 'reg_number', 'roll_number']
```

the follow code is in create_student.html file

```
            <tr>
                <td><label for="guardian">Guardian:</label></td>
                <td>{{ std_profile_form.guardian }}</td>
            </tr>
```

the following is sites.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite

accounts_admin_site = AdminSite(name='accounts_custom_admin')
```

the following is admin.py

```
from .sites import accounts_admin_site
class StudentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = StudentProfileForm
accounts_admin_site.register(Parent, admin.ModelAdmin)
accounts_admin_site.register(Student,StudentModelAdmin)
```

in the following link is picture, you can see a guardian field that has no styling I want to style that field
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtYQzlRRDTuAhc4N7bwS0q24j11P5Q?e=2aPZwr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of setting style for inputs in forms is widgets. you can try this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StudentProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['guardian'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'selectpicker'
```

Comment: let me add some more code to the question, may be the issue resides somewhere else

Comment: this worked but not I want to apply all the attributes only to the guardian field whereas it applies to all the fields that are visible.

Comment: i edit answer and i think this will solve your problem

Comment: I just want to ask one more thing that how can we add value attribute to the option tag of select in this situation.